# Can i make requests using a cookie in a nuxtjs middleware

Tags: frontend, nuxt.js, fetch, middleware, nuxtjs3

I am using the fetch api to request the current users identity from my express backend in my pinia store. However the cookie is not sent to the backend even though it has `credentials: 'include'` and the same request goes trough when done in the setup script of my `index.vue`. However if i use `onMounted` or a middleware it fails to include said cookie. I need the page to not be rendered if the user is logged in but since middlewares and "lifecycle" functions fail to make the request this is not possible.

Comment: Could you please show some specific examples with code?